# Cannot launch SparkPi example on Kubernetes Spark 2.4.0

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I've been trying to simply run the SparkPi example on Kubernetes with Spark 2.4.0 and it doesn't seem to behave at all like in the documentation.

I followed [the guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/running-on-kubernetes.html). I built a vanilla docker image with the `docker-image-tool.sh` script. Added it to my registry.

I launch the job from my spark folder with a command like this:

```
bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<spark-image> \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=mynamespace \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=myPullSecret \
    local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar
```

This is virtually the same as in the documentation except for the `namespace` and `pullSecrets` options. I need these options because of constraints in a multi user kubernetes environment. Even so I tried using the default namespace and I got the same outcome.

What happens is that the pod gets stuck in the failed state and two abnormal conditions occur:

- There's an error: `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-conf-volume" : configmaps "spark-pi-1547643379283-driver-conf-map" not found`. Indicating that k8s could not mount the config map to /opt/spark/conf which should contain a properties file. The config map (with the same name) exists so I don't understand why k8s cannot mount it.
- In the container logs there are several essential environment variables in the launch command that are empty.

container log:

```
CMD=(${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java "${SPARK_JAVA_OPTS[@]}" -cp "$SPARK_CLASSPATH" -Xms$SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY -Xmx$SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY -Dspark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS $SPARK_DRIVER_CLASS $SPARK_DRIVER_ARGS)
exec /sbin/tini -s -- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java -cp ':/opt/spark/jars/*' -Xms -Xmx -Dspark.driver.bindAddress=10.11.12.13
```

You can control some of these variables directly with properties such as `spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_DRIVER_CLASS` but this should not be necessary as (in this example the class is already specified with `--class`).

For clarity the following environment variables are empty:

- `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY`
- `SPARK_DRIVER_CLASS`
- `SPARK_DRIVER_ARGS`

The `SPARK_CLASSPATH` is also missing the container-local jar I specified on the command line (spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar).

It seems that even if we resolve the problem with mounting the configmap it won't help populate `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY` because it does not contain an equivalent configuration parameter.

How do I resolve the problem of mounting the config map and how do I resolve these environment variables?

The kubernetes yaml configuration is created by Spark, but in case it help I am posting here:

pod-spec.yaml

```
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "spark-pi-1547644451461-driver",
        "namespace": "frank",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/frank/pods/spark-pi-1547644451461-driver",
        "uid": "90c9577c-1990-11e9-8237-00155df6cf35",
        "resourceVersion": "19241392",
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-01-16T13:13:50Z",
        "labels": {
          "spark-app-selector": "spark-6eafcf5825e94637974f39e5b8512028",
          "spark-role": "driver"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "spark-local-dir-1",
            "emptyDir": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "spark-conf-volume",
            "configMap": {
              "name": "spark-pi-1547644451461-driver-conf-map",
              "defaultMode": 420
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "default-token-rfz9m",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "default-token-rfz9m",
              "defaultMode": 420
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "spark-kubernetes-driver",
            "image": "my-repo:10001/spark:latest",
            "args": [
              "driver",
              "--properties-file",
              "/opt/spark/conf/spark.properties",
              "--class",
              "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
              "spark-internal"
            ],
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "driver-rpc-port",
                "containerPort": 7078,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "blockmanager",
                "containerPort": 7079,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "spark-ui",
                "containerPort": 4040,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "status.podIP"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS",
                "value": "/var/data/spark-368106fd-09e1-46c5-a443-eec0b64b5cd9"
              },
              {
                "name": "SPARK_CONF_DIR",
                "value": "/opt/spark/conf"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "memory": "1408Mi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "1",
                "memory": "1408Mi"
              }
            },
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "spark-local-dir-1",
                "mountPath": "/var/data/spark-368106fd-09e1-46c5-a443-eec0b64b5cd9"
              },
              {
                "name": "spark-conf-volume",
                "mountPath": "/opt/spark/conf"
              },
              {
                "name": "default-token-rfz9m",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Never",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "serviceAccountName": "default",
        "serviceAccount": "default",
        "nodeName": "kube-worker16",
        "securityContext": {},
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "mypullsecret"
          }
        ],
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
        "tolerations": [
          {
            "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
            "operator": "Exists",
            "effect": "NoExecute",
            "tolerationSeconds": 300
          },
          {
            "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
            "operator": "Exists",
            "effect": "NoExecute",
            "tolerationSeconds": 300
          }
        ]
      },
      "status": {
        "phase": "Failed",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "Initialized",
            "status": "True",
            "lastProbeTime": null,
            "lastTransitionTime": "2019-01-16T13:15:11Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Ready",
            "status": "False",
            "lastProbeTime": null,
            "lastTransitionTime": "2019-01-16T13:15:11Z",
            "reason": "ContainersNotReady",
            "message": "containers with unready status: [spark-kubernetes-driver]"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainersReady",
            "status": "False",
            "lastProbeTime": null,
            "lastTransitionTime": null,
            "reason": "ContainersNotReady",
            "message": "containers with unready status: [spark-kubernetes-driver]"
          },
          {
            "type": "PodScheduled",
            "status": "True",
            "lastProbeTime": null,
            "lastTransitionTime": "2019-01-16T13:13:50Z"
          }
        ],
        "hostIP": "10.1.2.3",
        "podIP": "10.11.12.13",
        "startTime": "2019-01-16T13:15:11Z",
        "containerStatuses": [
          {
            "name": "spark-kubernetes-driver",
            "state": {
              "terminated": {
                "exitCode": 1,
                "reason": "Error",
                "startedAt": "2019-01-16T13:15:23Z",
                "finishedAt": "2019-01-16T13:15:23Z",
                "containerID": "docker://931908c3cfa6c2607c9d493c990b392f1e0a8efceff0835a16aa12afd03ec275"
              }
            },
            "lastState": {},
            "ready": false,
            "restartCount": 0,
            "image": "my-repo:10001/spark:latest",
            "imageID": "docker-pullable://my-repo:10001/spark@sha256:58e319143187d3a0df14ceb29a874b35756c4581265f0e1de475390a2d3e6ed7",
            "containerID": "docker://931908c3cfa6c2607c9d493c990b392f1e0a8efceff0835a16aa12afd03ec275"
          }
        ],
        "qosClass": "Burstable"
      }
    }
```

config-map.yml

```
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "spark-pi-1547644451461-driver-conf-map",
    "namespace": "frank",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/frank/configmaps/spark-pi-1547644451461-driver-conf-map",
    "uid": "90eda9e3-1990-11e9-8237-00155df6cf35",
    "resourceVersion": "19241350",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-01-16T13:13:50Z",
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Pod",
        "name": "spark-pi-1547644451461-driver",
        "uid": "90c9577c-1990-11e9-8237-00155df6cf35",
        "controller": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "spark.properties": "#Java properties built from Kubernetes config map with name: spark-pi-1547644451461-driver-conf-map\r\n#Wed Jan 16 13:14:12 GMT 2019\r\nspark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-1547644451461-driver\r\nspark.driver.host=spark-pi-1547644451461-driver-svc.frank.svc\r\nspark.kubernetes.container.image=aow-repo\\:10001/spark\\:latest\r\nspark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=mypullsecret\r\nspark.executor.instances=5\r\nspark.app.id=spark-6eafcf5825e94637974f39e5b8512028\r\nspark.app.name=spark-pi\r\nspark.driver.port=7078\r\nspark.kubernetes.resource.type=java\r\nspark.master=k8s\\://https\\://10.1.2.2\\:6443\r\nspark.kubernetes.python.pyFiles=\r\nspark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix=spark-pi-1547644451461\r\nspark.kubernetes.namespace=frank\r\nspark.driver.blockManager.port=7079\r\nspark.jars=/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar\r\nspark.submit.deployMode=cluster\r\nspark.kubernetes.submitInDriver=true\r\n"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your .yaml files?

Comment: I didn't write any yaml files myself. They are auto-generated by the `spark-submit` tool. I will see if I can share the generated configuration, or parts of it.

Comment: I've posted the yaml configs.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I now encounter a same situation and do not know how to go further.

Answer (score 7):

Spark on Kubernetes has a bug.

During Spark job submission to the Kubernetes cluster we first create Spark Driver Pod: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/02c5b4f76337cc3901b8741887292bb4478931f3/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/submit/KubernetesClientApplication.scala#L130 .

Only after that we create all other resources (eg.: Spark Driver Service), including ConfigMap: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/02c5b4f76337cc3901b8741887292bb4478931f3/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/submit/KubernetesClientApplication.scala#L135 .

We do that so to be able to set Spark Driver Pod as the `ownerReference` to all of those resources (which cannot be done before we create the owner Pod): https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/02c5b4f76337cc3901b8741887292bb4478931f3/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/submit/KubernetesClientApplication.scala#L134.

It helps us to delegate the deletion of all those resources to the Kubernetes responsibility, which is useful for collecting the unused resources more easily in the cluster. All we need to cleanup in that case is just delete Spark Driver Pod. But there is a risk that Kubernetes will instantiate Spark Driver Pod creation before the ConfigMap is ready, which will cause your issue.

This is still true for 2.4.4.

Comment: Is there a solution to the bug?

Comment: Some time ago I played around that and haven't come up with a solid solution. Kubernetes Api doesn't allow to add `ownerReference`s to not existing resources, which introduces a tradeoff: either we clean unused resources easily or we have such a flicker. One more to note, this is more frequently reproducible if you submit Spark job from the environment which has bigger latency on the connection to the Kubernetes Api, eg. from local machine to the Cloud based cluster. I haven't got that problem when submitted job from within Kubernetes cluster, seems we win the race in that case.

Comment: could you create a pod that owns the spark driver pods? then the ConfigMap could be created before the Spark Driver Pod and the meta-pod could be the ownerReference of the ConfigMap and other resources. this would eliminate the data race. however, i don't know the benefits/drawbacks/feasibility of this scheme, as i'm very new to kubernetes and cluster computing in general

Comment: @errolflynn cool idea, theoretically it can be not necessary pod and any Kubernetes resource should work. Need to think how it can be fit into the architecture, but sounds like it may be a solution. Then for the cleanup you just need to remove that `new resource` to trigger all others deletion.

Comment: Anyone got this problem solved? i am facing same issue on local (minikube)

Comment: Still true for spark3.1.1 (hadoop3.2, java11). Basing my docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/datamechanics/spark.  Submitting from laptop failed (also with `container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "driver": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`). Submitting from a pod on the cluster works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is mostly with the fact that my docker 'latest' tag was pointing at an image that was for the previous version of spark (v2.3.2). It seems that way the container receives parameters from spark-submit and kubernetes has changed a bit. My remaining problems launch spark pipelines seem to be with serviceAccounts (and probably belong in another question).